# Cordova , Keyboard is covering the Text Fields

Tags: html, cordova

I am using Cordva fromawork to Build an App, but my problem in the App is the Keyboard is covering the fields and unable to see the fields below the Keyboard
Can  anyone Help me to get out of this Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to my AndroidManifiest.xml